# Graphics.Draw out of Memory Issue

Tags: c#, bitmap, stack-trace

I seem to be getting an out of memory exception when I perform some image manipulation, but I am not sure why, or exactly where. The stack trace is as follows:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original)
```

Which is followed up seconds later by a similar out of memory exception:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
```

The code that I think is producing this is as follows:

```
  public static MemoryStream ResizeImage(this Bitmap bitmap, int destHeight, int destWidth, ImageFormat imageFormat)
    {
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        var xRes = bitmap.VerticalResolution;
        var yRes = bitmap.HorizontalResolution;
        var largestRes = xRes > yRes ? xRes : yRes;
        var factor = Math.Abs(xRes / yRes);
        bitmap.SetResolution(largestRes, largestRes);
        if (destHeight == 0)
            destHeight = (int)(xRes != largestRes ? bitmap.Height / factor : bitmap.Height);
        if (destWidth == 0)
            destWidth = (int)(yRes != largestRes ? bitmap.Width / factor : bitmap.Width);
        using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)b))
            {
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
            }
            b.Save(mem, imageFormat);
        }
        return mem;
    }
```

I know this is doing a lot of image crunching, but is there anything inherently wrong with this?

Comment: There is something wrong with it, that MemoryStream is not usable as-is.  Add `mem.Position = 0;`  Kinda pointless to only post partial stack traces btw.  Not calling the Dispose() method on the Image and Bitmap objects you manipulate is a very common bug..

Answer (score 1):

Code is ok but GDI+ can throw the OutOfMemoryException when pixel format of the image is not supported.

Check the image to ensure that it is supported.